# Serialization of derived class trips Boost assertion

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

When trying to serialize a derived class with `boost::serialization`, an assertion in `boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp` (line 436 in Boost 1.53.0) is tripped:

```
const basic_pointer_oserializer * bpos
    = static_cast<const basic_pointer_oserializer *>(
        boost::serialization::singleton<
            archive_serializer_map<Archive>
        >::get_const_instance().find(*true_type)
    );
BOOST_ASSERT(NULL != bpos);
```

Here is my MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_xml_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

class base
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("test", test);
    }

    int test;

public:
    virtual void print() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
};

class derived : public base
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("base", boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this));
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("test2", test2);
    }

    int test2;

public:
    void print() { std::cout << 2 << std::endl; }
};

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    base *b = new derived();

    std::ofstream stream("out.xml");
    boost::archive::polymorphic_xml_oarchive ar(stream);
    ar.register_type<derived>();
    ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("b", b);

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried using `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` instead of `register_type`, but that also didn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't mean to use [polymorphic_xml_archive (see docs)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/archive_reference.html#polymorphic).

Notably, *polymorphic archives* have to do with the interface of the archives, nothing with the entities you're serializing for (they can always be polymorphic).

If you use `xml_archive` instead, the problem vanishes.